# How to tell which GUI was used to provide the correct service? (Java client / server)

Tags: java, user-interface, service, client

I have 3 GUI forms:

NewUser.java

ExistingUser.java

ForgotLogin.java

Each of these has a button that when clicked, opens a connection on port 22402.

Now my server class (websiteserver.java) accepts the connection and starts off a thread on the service class (websiteservice.java). This class implements runnable and simply calls each separate service to provide and prints back to the client.

The issue that I'm having is HOW can I tell which GUI form was submitted in the first place to provide that specific service in my websiteservice class? I tried making 3 different ports but then I can only have one `serversocket.accept();` on the server. So how can I make this work?

I hope this makes sense..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing whatever your service does involves data the user entered on these client forms. Perhaps when you send that data to the server, include some type of form ID to indicate which form the user was on.